# Merge multiple configuration files using powershell

Tags: powershell, office365, dsc

My Powershell script receives multiple Microsoft Office365 DSC policy configuration policy files as input in a folder as below:

file1.ps1

```
Configuration EXOSharingPolicy {
    param (
        [parameter()]
        [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]
        $GlobalAdmin
    )

    if ($null -eq $GlobalAdmin) {
        <# Credentials #>
        $GlobalAdmin = Get-Credential -Message "Credentials"

    }
    else {
        $Credential = $GlobalAdmin
    }

    $OrganizationName = $Credential.UserName.Split('@')[1]
    Import-DscResource -ModuleName 'Microsoft365DSC' -ModuleVersion '1.22.907.1'

    Node localhost
    {
        EXOSharingPolicy 8b39ae5a-f4ed-4bdb-932d-fbb9397f7fc6
        {
            Credential           = $Credential;
            Default              = $True;
            Domains              = @("Anonymous:CalendarSharingFreeBusyReviewer");
            Enabled              = $True;
            Ensure               = "Present";
            Name                 = "Default Sharing Policy";
        }
    }
}
```

file2.ps1

```
Configuration AADTenantDetails {
    param (
        [parameter()]
        [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]
        $GlobalAdmin
    )

    if ($null -eq $GlobalAdmin) {
        <# Credentials #>
        $GlobalAdmin = Get-Credential -Message "Credentials"

    }
    else {
        $Credential = $GlobalAdmin
    }

    $OrganizationName = $Credential.UserName.Split('@')[1]
    Import-DscResource -ModuleName 'Microsoft365DSC' -ModuleVersion '1.22.907.1'

    Node localhost
    {
        AADTenantDetails 5cfcabd5-9c82-4bed-9934-09e1cf20c71b
        {
            Credential                           = $Credential;
            IsSingleInstance                     = "Yes";
            MarketingNotificationEmails          = @();
            SecurityComplianceNotificationMails  = @();
            SecurityComplianceNotificationPhones = @();
            TechnicalNotificationMails           = @("admin@tech.net.au");
        }
    }
}
```

file3.ps1

```
Configuration EXOEmailAddressPolicy {
    param (
        [parameter()]
        [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]
        $GlobalAdmin
    )

    if ($null -eq $GlobalAdmin) {
        <# Credentials #>
        $GlobalAdmin = Get-Credential -Message "Credentials"

    }
    else {
        $Credential = $GlobalAdmin
    }

    $OrganizationName = $Credential.UserName.Split('@')[1]
    Import-DscResource -ModuleName 'Microsoft365DSC' -ModuleVersion '1.22.907.1'

    Node localhost
    {
        EXOEmailAddressPolicy a2188f3f-80d5-419c-b229-063fc2c18dbf
        {
            Credential                        = $Credential;
            EnabledEmailAddressTemplates      = @("SMTP:@$OrganizationName");
            EnabledPrimarySMTPAddressTemplate = "@$OrganizationName";
            Ensure                            = "Present";
            ManagedByFilter                   = "";
            Name                              = "Default Policy";
            Priority                          = "Lowest";
        }
    }
}
```

I have several of these configuration files.
Is there a way in powershell to combine/merge these files so I end up with one file with all configurations like below.

```
Configuration CombinedPolicy {
    param (
        [parameter()]
        [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]
        $GlobalAdmin
    )

    if ($null -eq $GlobalAdmin) {
        <# Credentials #>
        $GlobalAdmin = Get-Credential -Message "Credentials"

    }
    else {
        $Credential = $GlobalAdmin
    }

    $OrganizationName = $Credential.UserName.Split('@')[1]
    Import-DscResource -ModuleName 'Microsoft365DSC' -ModuleVersion '1.22.907.1'

    Node localhost
    {
        EXOSharingPolicy 8b39ae5a-f4ed-4bdb-932d-fbb9397f7fc6
        {
            Credential           = $Credential;
            Default              = $True;
            Domains              = @("Anonymous:CalendarSharingFreeBusyReviewer");
            Enabled              = $True;
            Ensure               = "Present";
            Name                 = "Default Sharing Policy";
        }
        AADTenantDetails 5cfcabd5-9c82-4bed-9934-09e1cf20c71b
        {
            Credential                           = $Credential;
            IsSingleInstance                     = "Yes";
            MarketingNotificationEmails          = @();
            SecurityComplianceNotificationMails  = @();
            SecurityComplianceNotificationPhones = @();
            TechnicalNotificationMails           = @("jarrod@j-tech.net.au");
        }
        EXOEmailAddressPolicy a2188f3f-80d5-419c-b229-063fc2c18dbf
        {
            Credential                        = $Credential;
            EnabledEmailAddressTemplates      = @("SMTP:@$OrganizationName");
            EnabledPrimarySMTPAddressTemplate = "@$OrganizationName";
            Ensure                            = "Present";
            ManagedByFilter                   = "";
            Name                              = "Default Policy";
            Priority                          = "Lowest";
        }
    }
}
```

So, in the combined configuration file I only need the section under `Node localhost` from each of the individual configuration files to be combined instead of entire file contents merged.

I need this so I can apply all the DSC configurations an office 365 tenancy at once instead of applying individual configurations.

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The following script gets the desired combined file. You can only have the DSC files in the folder "PathToDSCFiles". This also only works if the given DSC files all have a format like given in the examples, because it just skips the 21 lines in the given scripts and continues from there. If you have other formats from your files, you will have to find a way to just select everything that comes after "Node Localhost".

```
$path = "PathToDSCFiles"
$PathToCombinedFile = "PathToCombinedFile"
$list = (Get-ChildItem -Path $path).Name
$first = $list | select -First 1

$SecondWord = (Get-Content $path\$first).Split(" ")[1]
((Get-Content $path\$first)[0]) -creplace($SecondWord,"CombinedPolicy") > $PathToCombinedFile
Get-Content $path\$first | select -skip 1 | select -skipLast 2 >> $PathToCombinedFile
foreach($file in ($list | select -skip 1)){
    if ($file -eq ($list | select -skip 1)[-1]){
        Get-Content -Path $path\$file | select -Skip 21 >> $PathToCombinedFile
    }else{
        Get-Content -Path $path\$file | select -Skip 21 | select -SkipLast 2 >> $PathToCombinedFile
    }
}
```